# Aligning text using html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to align the text so that the TITLE is centered on the page, which I got to work. I want to make the typewriter effect begin below the TITLE and centered. I messed around with it a bit but I can't figure out how to get it below the text. I am able to bring it to the middle, but not to the center. I also want the line structure to remain if that makes sense and not center each line individually.

```css
/* TITLE */

.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

/* TYPEWRITER EFFECT */

.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 7.3em;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 11.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 7.3em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">TITLE</a></h1>

    <h2 class="css-typing">
        <p>
            Typed text 1
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 2 Longer
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 3
        </p>
    </h2>
```

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue and whether you liked my suggestion or do I need to ameliorate my skills and suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, I think the following may solve your problem, but you can tweak the positioning until you're happy!

```
<h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>

<div class="css-typing">
    <p>
        Typed text 1
    </p>
    <p>
        Typed text 2 Longer
    </p>
    <p>
        Typed text 3
    </p>
</div>
```

And then the CSS along the lines of how you've positioned your Title:

```
/* TITLE */

.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

/* TYPEWRITER EFFECT */

.css-typing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 46%;
}

.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 7.3em;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 11.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 7.3em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue is that the paragraphs overwrite each other. i can definitely mess around with each one until i get it, but is there no way to just move it all at once so i don't have to do that?

Comment: The code above should move all p elements as a block and not overwrite each other.  Make sure you change the HTML as well because you had an H2 tag where there should have been a div.

Answer (score 1):

Try the attached code it will surely work and if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to assist you.

In the answer I have added margin to `.css-typing` and changed `<h2>` into a `<div>` because you should not insert `<p>` inside `<h2>` for that you should use `<div>`.

And I have a suggestion for you that use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` and `%` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

```css
        .title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

/* TYPEWRITER EFFECT */
.css-typing{

  margin-left: 45vw;
  margin-top: 60vh;
}
.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 7.3em;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 11.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 7.3em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="title">TITLE</a></h1>

    <div class="css-typing">
        <p>
            Typed text 1
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 2 Longer
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 3
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on a similar way to the title, but for the h2 element:

```
h2 {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 60%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doe.

Here is a solution to your question. Let me know if that works.

```css
/* TITLE */

.title {
    text-align: center;
}

p{
   position: relative;
   left:50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   
}




/* TYPEWRITER EFFECT */

.css-typing p {
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 7.3em;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 11.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 7.3em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 5s steps(20, end), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>

    
   <div class="css-typing">
        <p>
            Typed text 1
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 2 Longer
        </p>
        <p>
            Typed text 3
        </p>
    </div>
```